# Is Miss Matheson from Diamond Age, YT from Snow Crash?

Tags: neal-stephenson, snow-crash, diamond-age

In *Diamond Age* the character Miss Matheson alludes to her past in a reminiscence concerning the 'smart wheels' on her wheel chair. She likens them to those on skateboards and then talks about how she was once a 'thrasher'.
This strongly suggests that Miss Matheson is YT from *Snow Crash*.

This is mentioned in the following Wikipedia article [Wikipedia - *Diamond Age*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Diamond_Age#Snow_Crash) and repeated in [this answer to a previous SFF question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/650/what-is-the-connection-between-snow-crash-and-the-diamond-age).

This is obviously speculation on the part of Wikipedia although it makes perfect (and poetic) sense - I love the idea that an ex-thrasher 'wild child' became a prim and proper neo-Victorian school mistress in her later years.

The question is, has this ever been confirmed by Neal Stephenson?

Comment: I've never seen official confirmation, but it certainly appears so.  This is hearsay, but a commenter on Slashdot [said](http://news.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=200&cid=1837042) "Yes, YT is Miss Matheson...or near enough it doesn't matter. Someone asked Stephenson about this at a reading in Boston, and Stephenson said that it's certainly okay to think so."

Comment: @pooter03 - I think that's as close as we're going to get - post your comment as an answer . . .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never seen official confirmation, but it certainly appears so. This is hearsay, but a commenter on Slashdot [said](https://news.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=200&cid=1837042) <sup>(comment removed due to account deletion and can't find an archive for it at the moment)</sup>:

> Yes, YT is Miss Matheson...or near enough it doesn't matter. Someone asked Stephenson about this at a reading in Boston, and Stephenson said that it's certainly okay to think so.